# assign javascript variable to twig variable symfony 2

Tags: javascript, twig

I would like to assign the value of a Javascript variable to a twig variable like this :

```
$(".change-mod").click(function(){
   var id=$(this).attr("id");
   {{% set page =  'here i want to assign id to page' %}}
});
```

How can I do it?

Comment: Twig code is executed on the server. Javascript is executed on the client. You can't transfer data between them in this way.

Comment: any suggestions in how to do it ?

Comment: Hard to say without knowing what your purpose is. The solution might be AJAX; it might be Javascript templates; it might be simple DOM manipulation; it might be a normal HTTP request. You're going to have to work out what best suits your purpose.

Comment: Maybe by sending `AJAX` request but, needless to say, any `Twig` variable is volatile as it will expire at the end of the request...

Answer (score 3):

It is simple not possible. These are two different things.

Javascript runs on client browser and TWIG templating system is generated on server.

You can replace generated HTML content by Javascript only on generated page or by AJAX request and your content from server response.

Answer (score 1):

this my stupid solve

```
$(".change-mod").click(function(){
   var id=$(this).attr("id");
$.ajax({
         url: 'jstotwig.php',
         type: 'POST',
         data: {id: id},
       success: function(data) {
                var page =  "here i want to assign"+data+"to page"
                }
         });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Bare in mind, that it will not really allow you to assign javascript variables to twig variables, but it will allow you to generate paths on the client side as you can read here http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/routing.html#generating-urls , the documentation points to a bundle, that lets you do exactly that https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSJsRoutingBundle , it may be even possible to assign javascript variables to twigs, but that is not what this bundle does.